# Read or write file on system dbus without dependencie

Tags: dbus, systemd

I need to read (write later) a file with dbus method like:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager LoadUnit s fstrim.service
```

I get object path

```
o "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/fstrim_2eservice"
```

Now, I would like to display its contents.
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/692771/find-the-location-of-a-systemd-service/692776).

You want to query the `FragmentPath` property of the `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit` interface on that object path.

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/NetworkManager_2eservice org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit FragmentPath 
s "/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service"
```

That gives you the filename to load and display.

Comment: Is there a way to get the contents of the file (raw) via dbus method?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Why should there be? There are file system APIs for that already in the system library.